# .NET MVC - pass database table from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC application in which I want to display data about exchange market. I have three tables in my database (EurUsd, EurChf and UsdJpy). In my application, I made three models named like the tables from the database.
   In my  view, I have three action links, and when the user clicks on one of them they call a specific method from the controller.

Since the methods are similar, just the database table is different, I'm wondering if it is possible to pass the table from the view to the controller and how to write it in the controller.

I know how to send data from the view to the controller, but i can't figure it out how to select the table from which to retrive the data.

Here is my code:

### Controller

```
public ActionResult EurUsdData()
        {
            var model = from r in db.EurUsd
                        orderby r.DATE ascending
                        select new Currency
                        {
                            ID = r.EurUsdID,
                            DATE = r.DATE,
                            OPEN = r.OPEN,
                            LOW = r.LOW,
                            HIGH = r.HIGH
                        };
            return PartialView("_CurrencyTable", model.ToList());
        }

        public ActionResult EurChfData()
        {
            var model = from r in db.EurChf
                        orderby r.DATE ascending
                        select new Currency
                        {
                            ID = r.EurChfID,
                            DATE = r.DATE,
                            OPEN = r.OPEN,
                            LOW = r.LOW,
                            HIGH = r.HIGH
                        };
            return PartialView("_CurrencyTable", model.ToList());
        }

        public ActionResult UsdJpyData()
        {
            var model = from r in db.UsdJpy
                        orderby r.DATE ascending
                        select new Currency
                        {
                            ID = r.UsdJpyID,
                            DATE = r.DATE,
                            OPEN = r.OPEN,
                            LOW = r.LOW,
                            HIGH = r.HIGH
                        };
            return PartialView("_CurrencyTable", model.ToList());
        }
```

### View

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav"
    <li>
        <div class="sidebar-brand">
            Meniu
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        @Ajax.ActionLink("EUR / USD", "EurUsdData", "Currencies",new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "CurrencyTableSection" });
    </li>
    <li>
        @Ajax.ActionLink("EUR / CHF", "EurChfData", "Currencies", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "CurrencyTableSection" });
    </li>
    <li>
        @Ajax.ActionLink("USD / JPY", "UsdJpyData", "Currencies", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "CurrencyTableSection" });
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you!

Comment: As a first guess it sounds like the tables are so similar that it should actually be one table. This way you would not have the problem of selecting different model classes. What is the content of the tables?

Comment: Each table contains the exchange value for that pair. For example, in EurUsd table I have all the data from 2001 to present, in UsdJpy the exchange rate from 2001 to present and so on. The tables have the same structure, just the data is different.    What I'm trying to do, is make a method which takes a parameter (table) from which to retrieve data.

Comment: The data layer is missing, all the job is being done in the controller. If you had a data layer, all you need is to pass the table from action method to a common method that queries the table. This will solve your problem and also it's a better design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, since it seems like you're already in good shape. For example, clicking the "EUR / USD" link routes to the `EurUsdData` action, which then utilizes the `EurUsd` `DbSet`. There's no need to specify a table because the correct one is being utilized by going to the appropriate action.

If your intent is to have just one generic action instead of these three separate actions, I would actually suggest the same advice as @Tim in the comments: there's no reason for these to be three separate tables in the first place. The schema is all the same, so all you need is to add a column or two that allows you to discriminate between the various exchange rates. For example, you could add a `FROM` and a `TO` column, such that your values currently in `EurUsd` would have `FROM` as "EUR" and `TO` as "USD". Then, you can simply query that single dataset based on those columns to get just the subset you need.

Comment: Yes, I wanted just a generic method, because I try to keep my code as simple as possible, and in the curent configuration it is reduntand. Thank you, I will try to redesign my database.